# How to calculate proportion of the population

Tags: population, epidemiology, population-attributable-fraction

I am trying to calculate population attributable fraction. The formula that i am using is

$$
\frac{P_e(RR-1)}{P_e(RR-1) + 1}
$$

I am using this website as guide: https://sphweb.bumc.bu.edu/otlt/mph-modules/ep/ep713_association/EP713_Association7.html

I am unable to understand how did they calculate $P_e$. It says that its proportion of exposed subjects in entire population. The entire population here is 100,000 and total exposed subjects are 10,000 (500 with disease and 9500 without disease). If i do $10000/100000$ then the answer is $0.1$. How did the website shows its $0.2$?

Answer (score 0):

You've probably already foudn where you made the mistake, but for completion, I wanted to explain.

The webpage you just cited was NOT referring to the table when calculating the PAF. In fact, all the information for the example you just stated can be found in the sentence immediately preceding the calculation.

> For example, if we know that the relative risk for the effect of smoking on lung cancer is approximately 20, and our surveillance system data tell us that 20% of the adult population of the U.S. smokes, we can calculate the proportion of all lung cancer cases in the population that are attributable to smoking.

If you were to use the information contained in this sentence, the calculation of the PAF using the formula given follows.

Good luck.